# How can I change the org export title, for PDF?

Tags: org-export, pdf

When exporting org files to pdf, is it possible to make the title that shows up in the exported document different from what is in the `#+title` field in the org file?

For example, I have an org file whose title is `#+title: Org tile` and I want the pdf to display "PDF title" as its title. How can I do this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What's wrong with changing the title, exporting to PDF and then undoing the change?

Comment: Nothing. Just thought this should be easier. And to me it would be interesting to keep both titles in a single document

Comment: You can keep both there with one commented out - then switch the commenting when you want to export to PDF.